# $x^x=2$ how do you solve?

Tags: logarithms

Is this possible to solve algebraically? I couldn't figure out a way and got approximately 1.5591... and I couldn't see any relationship between that number and any other logarithmic numbers. Is this possible to solve without just guessing and checking?

Comment: This equation requires that new functions.  Wiki "Lambert's W".  The solution to this equation is $x = \frac{\ln 2}{\mbox{LambertW}(\ln 2)}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
x^x &= z\\
x\ln x &= \ln z\\
e^{\ln x}\ln x &= \ln z.
\end{align}
Since for all $t\geq0$ the [*Lambert W function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) has the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities)
$$
W\left(t\cdot e^t\right) = t,
$$
for $t=\ln x$, we have $W\left(\ln x \cdot e^{\ln x}\right) = \ln x$, so by applying $W$ on both sides, we have
$$
\ln x = W\left(\ln z\right).
$$
From here [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2)
$$
x = e^{W\left(\ln z\right)},
$$
or since by the definiction of the $W$ function $\ln z = W\left(\ln z\right)e^{W\left(\ln z\right)}$, an equivalent solution is
$$
x = \frac{\ln z}{W\left(\ln z\right)}.
$$
For $z=2$ this argument answers your question.